# Fog Hides Skybox (THREE.JS R76)

Tags: javascript, three.js, skybox

I have a cylinder the camera stays in. I have fog set so the end of the tube isn't  visible - however I want the skybox to be visible through the alpha map sides of the cylinder. The fog blocks the visibility and am wondering what needs to be done to fix that.

```
var POS_X = 0,
    POS_Y = 0,
    POS_Z = 0,
    FOV = 60,
    WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
    HEIGHT = window.innerHeight,
    NEAR = 1,
    FAR = 120000, //Camera Far Distance
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true}),
```

............

```
function addFog(){
    scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(0x000000, 100, 40000);
}
```

............

```
function addSkybox(){
    var materialArray = [],
        imgArray = ["skybox_right.jpg", "skybox_left.jpg",
        "skybox_front.jpg", "skybox_back.jpg",
        "skybox_top.jpg", "skybox_bottom.jpg"];

    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        materialArray.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: loader.load( imgArray[i] ),
            side: THREE.BackSide
        }));
    }

    var skyMat = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materialArray ),
        skyGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 100000, 100000, 100000, 1, 1, 1),
        sky = new THREE.Mesh(skyGeo, skyMat);

    sky.name="skybox";
    scene.add(sky);
}
```

Comment: have you tried to divide the skybox into 6 different objects so that they wont be affected by fog? `.far`
_The maximum distance at which fog stops being calculated and applied. Objects that are more than 'far' units away from the active camera won't be affected by fog_

Comment: Hmmm i suppose I got confused with the wording. I was adding Meshes to the scene a nd they are objects but not Object3D. Seems like if I make the skybox an object 3D it will work then? I will have to try soon.

Comment: So I added the skybox to the scene as a seperate object 3D.  The cylinder was added also as a seperate object3D. There is no change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just add `fog: false` to ignore the fog effect.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    materialArray.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: loader.load( imgArray[i] ),
        side: THREE.BackSide,
        fog: false
    }));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very insightful. Exactly what I was looking for!